# Incorrect decrement of the reference count & memory leak

Tags: objective-c, release, avfoundation, memory-leaks, avaudiorecorder

With an 'Analyze', in the dealloc I get:
*Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller*

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface XYZViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain) AVAudioRecorder  *recorder;
@end
@implementation XYZViewController
@synthesize recorder;
- (void) dealloc
{
    [self.recorder release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];
    NSError *error;
    self.recorder = [[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error] autorelease];
}
@end
```

Does it mean I shouldn't release it?
Also, I tried to 'Profile' the code and I get a memory leak from `[[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error] autorelease]` no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than sending `-release` to the object returned by the property accessor method, set the property itself to `nil`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.recorder = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The compiler will know to do the right thing because you've specified the storage semantics in the property declaration. Synthesizing a property declared with `retain` semantics is effectively equivalent to writing the following accessor methods:

```
- (AVAudioRecorder *)recorder {
    return recorder;
}

- (void)setRecorder:(AVAudioRecorder *)newRecorder {
    [newRecorder retain];
    [recorder release];
    recorder = newRecorder;
}
```

When you write `self.recorder = nil`, the compiler translates it into `[self setRecorder:nil]`. Setting a property to `nil` in this way therefore avoids both memory leaks and dangling pointers, involves less boilerplate on your part, and more clearly expresses the intent of the code.

Finally, it never hurts to re-read [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), which has a section on declared properties; and [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i), which goes over all the different approaches to memory management in detail.

Comment: So `self.foo = nil;` is better than `[foo release]; foo = nil;`. I will use it in both dealloc and viewDidUnload. Thank you!

Comment: The only thing to watch out for with using `self.foo = nil;` in `-dealloc` (or for that matter, `self.foo = bar;` in `-init`) is that if you have written a custom implementation of `-setFoo:` that has a side effect, you might get a weird bug. Within the context of `-init` or `-dealloc`, your object is considered in an invalid or uninitialized state, so you have to be careful when sending any messages to `self`. However, in the common case of setting or clearing a simple property, I use the dot notation. Memory management bugs are more common by far than side-effect bugs.

Answer (score 4):

You should release the ivar directly, rather than going through the accessor:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [recorder release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You don't own the returned object of an accessor, so you shouldn't release it.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't solve the memory leak in the present case. And in `viewDidUnload`, after a `[foo release]` I should use `self.foo = nil` or `foo = nil`?

Comment: for the memory leak, it's apparently not my fault: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470744/avaudiorecorder-memory-leak